# Change the starting point of an animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I made an JavaScript animation of a div based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/15/ 
I am searching for a way to make the animation ***start*** from a precise point :
`Top : 10vh` and `Left : 90vw` but I can't seem to find how to do it without placing the animation outside the window

thought about using math like `($(window).width()/100*9))` 
 in order to have a vw size. But doesn't seem to work yet.
How could I achieve that ?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();

});

function makeNewPosition(){

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

Comment: How is it outside the window? ... well, if you set `left:90vw` and the window is smaller than 500px (a tenth of 500px is 50px), of course it goes outside ... then use CSS calc() like this: `left: calc(90vw - 50px);`

Comment: for example if I set  `margin-left:90%;`  to `div.a`  you will see that the animation is going out of the window

Comment: Of course it does, what else can possible happen when you move the div out of view/window? ... Maybe you can be more specific with what you want, maybe posting an image with the expected result

Comment: so you want the animation to still function  and be visible in any space even if its small?

Comment: @LGSon : you actually solve the problem with your answer. CSS calc works

Comment: When you set `margin-left` that value adds to the left position and since your script use the windows full width when calculate the new position it goes out of view

Comment: Yes. I actually knew that... Sunday morning I guess. But can't I set the start in javascript ?

Comment: Of course, use `$('.a').css()` ... and I posted an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS calc() like this: `left: calc(90vw - 50px);` to make it stay within the window, as long as the window is bigger than the div itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();
    
});

function makeNewPosition(){
    
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;
    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    
    return [nh,nw];    
    
}

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
    
    $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });
    
};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    
    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
    
    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
    
    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

```css
div.a {
  top: 10vh;
  left: calc(90vw - 50px);
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'></div>
```